# In Zombies, run! is it possible to see the Zombie Chases?

Tags: zombies-run

I'm fairly new to the app, and I've been caught by zombies several times. I failed the mission once, and I've lost about 18+ items just by dropping them so that I don't get caught/eaten.

My problem is I don't know where the zombies are coming from, so I don't know where to run. 
I've tried to look at my screen when a chase happens, but I can't see the chase on my screen.

Is there any option that I have to enable, so that I can see the chases? Is that even possible?
Do the zombies always come from behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to see the chases while you are running, because they're not directional. The way the chases work is that you are supposed to run 20% faster than you were going before the zombies appeared to outrun them.

Since it is only speed you need, not direction, there is no reason for them to show you the chase. Just make sure you run faster in whatever direction you choose when the app alerts you to a zombie chase, and you should be able to outrun them - they are intended to increase your speed for short bursts.

The chases will, however, show up when you view your route in Zombielink after your run.

Comment: That makes much more sense, Although I just found out that in zombielink you can actually see the chases, but you cannot see the chase in real time. I've only been running 15% faster so that's why I've been caught multiple times. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can see them after you are done, but not during. I should have clarified that.